# Automatic and periodic zipping (tar.gz) of directory files using shell script

Tags: bash, tar

I have a system that produces a set of files every day. These files have different formats, but their name is date.

```
fatemeh@Ubuntu:~ $ls
2020-06-19.all
2020-06-19.log
2020-06-19.ack
2020-06-19.eod
2020-06-20.log
2020-06-20.ack
2020-06-20.eod
2020-06-20.live
2020-06-21.log
2020-06-21.all
2020-06-21.live
2020-06-21.ack
```

I have to zip the files from three days ago into a file named the same day every day.
I have a script that compresses files in the specified directory by receiving the date.

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /home/ihubadm/history
####Asking user to enter Date and name######
echo -n "please enter date yy-mm-dd "
read -p 'Date:' datevar

tar -czvf $datevar.tar.gz $datevar.*

echo "Done! $datevar.tar.gz is now available!"
```

But I want this script to zip three days ago files by reading the current date.
I also tried this one:

```
datevar=$(date -d + '%Y-%m-%d') && tar -czvf "$datevar.tar.gz" "$datevar".*
```

but an error raised and it didn't work.

I've read similar pages, but none of them helped solve my problem.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi! Have you already tried something?

Comment: use `date` with desired format for example *date +"%m-%d-%Y"* (see `date --help`). you can save cmd output into variable with *var="$( ... )"* split strings with string manipulation *var=${var:6:4}* calculate with arithmetic expansion *var=$((var+1))* or concatenate *string="${var1}${var2}"*

Comment: @FrancescoLucianò ofcourse. I used 'datevar=&(date -d + '%Y-%m-%d') && tar -czvf "$datevar.tar.gz" "$datevar".*' but an error raised.

Comment: please edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve your problem, rather than extending unneeded discussion in a chain of every increasing comments ;-)!  Search here for `[bash] date arithmetic` and you should find many examples of using `date` to automatically generate the value you need. No need for `${var:6:4}` and the logic required to find 3 days before March 1. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter date arithmetic is not available on every `date`

Comment: @alecxs : Agreed! But look there first, right? ;-) Good luck to all!

Comment: you meant `datevar=$(....)` didn't you?

Comment: why don't you use `mtime` in combintaion of `find` I assume these files names are created as per the date/time it's created in system. `find <PathToFiles> -mtime +3 -exec tar -czvf "$datevar.tar.gz" "$datevar".* {} \;`

Comment: @change198 she's a student and it's a exercise (and mtime is not always true)